# Generating a Price report

Tags: price, reports

Is there a way I can generate are report showing all the product prices, showing what the normal RRP is, and if there is a sale price on an item what the sale price is?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow below steps :

1. Go to Admin > System  > Data Transfer > Export
2. Select "Entity Type" as "Products"
3. Scroll down and click Continue
4. Upon completion of the task, look for the file in the download location for your web browser.
5. You can save or open the exported CSV file as a spreadsheet, then edit the data and import it back into your store.

It may help to export product price report.

Comment: I am getting a blank report